# Probiotic expired Oct 2013

Tags: probiotics, expiration-dates, safety

I was doing some cleaning and came across sealed and packaged probiotic that expired Oct 2013.

Is it safe/effective to consume in Oct 2015?

Comment: Why the downvote. This is a simple question.

Answer (score 2):

***I would go with the expiration on the package. If the package says that it can only last till June 2015 or other date, I wouldn't try go very far past that. Also, make sure the package is intact and make sure it looks and smells edible.***

---

- [Probiotics can last 18 months](http://probiotics.mercola.com/probiotics-faq.html)

> Unrefrigerated, Complete Probiotics have an 18 months shelf life.

[Probiotics, shelf life and storage](http://www.symprove.com/blog/single/probiotics-shelf-life-and-storage), this may or may not be helpful.

[It is also interested to note,](http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/Transparency/Basics/ucm210073.htm)

> FDA does not require food firms to place "expired by", "use by" or
>   "best before" dates on food products. This information is entirely at
>   the discretion of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that expired probiotic capsules won’t hurt you, though they likely won’t give you the probiotic health benefits you were hoping for.

[All about probiotic shelf life](https://drruscio.com/do-probiotics-expire/)